# apply bold text on part of string Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngx-translate

I would like to make a part of my text bold.

I get a text from a specific file.

`"INFORMATION": "Here's an example of text",`

I would want that `Here's an` to be bold.

`"INFORMATION": "<b>Here's an</b> example of text",`

`"INFORMATION": "<strong>Here's an</strong> example of text"`

Then I print it

```
<span translate>INFORMATION</span>
```

Instead of getting

**Here's an** example of text

I get

```
<b>Here's an</b> example of text
```

or

```
<strong>Here's an</strong> example of text
```

**UPDATE**

I'm trying innerHTML

```
<span [innerHTML]="information | translate"></span>
```

*Information is variable containing text*

but it's ignoring my html tags, it's printing only text

Comment: Where is the code where you try and display the text? It looks like you are just passing in a string not a html.

Comment: `"INFORMATION": "<b>Here an</b> example of text",`Here's my code containing the text. Then I print it inside `<span>`

Comment: is `translate` your own class or did you use a framework/library?

Comment: I use ngx-translate

Answer (score 8):

What I would do is a pipe that sanitizes the string you're giving to it, and use a regex to make it more generic. Something like this stackblitz :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyz8b1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Sanitizer, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'boldSpan'
})
export class BoldSpanPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: Sanitizer
  ) {}

  transform(value: string, regex): any {
    return this.sanitize(this.replace(value, regex));
  }

  replace(str, regex) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(`(${regex})`, 'gi'), '<b>$1</b>');
  }

  sanitize(str) {
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, str);
  }
}
```

This way, the variable content doesn't actually change, meaning your data remains untouched.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

changing @user4676340's answer, to match string that is written like this:
"blabla *bold* blabla"  to return "blabla **bold** blabla"  - Whatsapp style

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Sanitizer, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { noop } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({
  name: 'boldText'
})
export class BoldTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: Sanitizer) { }

  transform(value: string): any {
    const regex = /[\*][\w\W]*[\*]/gmi;
    return this.sanitize(this.replace(value, regex));
  }

  replace(str, regex) {
    let matched = str.match(regex);
    matched ? matched.forEach(foundString => {
      foundString = foundString.substring(1, foundString.length - 1);
      str = str.replace(regex, `<b>${foundString}</b>`);
    }) : noop;
    return str;
  }

  sanitize(str) {
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, str);
  }
}
```

(using innerHTML in the component template)

TS: `text="blabla \*bold\* blabla"`

HTML: `<p [innerHTML]="text | boldText"></p>`

Comment: how to apply if it is in the tag like this: <p>{{ data.text }}</p>

Comment: add to innerHTML of Paragraph. it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the whole context of the task, but here is a simple solution. I hope that's enough. (But we are dealing with "apply bold text on part of string Angular".) The changing from @user4676340 and the following edits are good

`// app.components.ts`

```
item = {"INFORMATION": "Here's an", "TEXT": " example of text"};
item3 = "Here's an";
item3_1 = " example of text";
```

`// app.components.html`

Variant 1 :

```
<p>
<b><span>{{item.INFORMATION}}</span></b>
<span>{{item.TEXT}}</span>
</p>
```

Variant 2:

```
<p>
<b><span [innerHTML]="item3"></span></b>
<span [innerHTML]="item3_1"></span>
</p>
```

Result: **Here's an** example of text

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [angular-translate 2.0](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive) if you have it.

```
<span translate="{{ 'INFORMATION' }}"></span>
```

Comment: It's only for Angular 1.x ?

Answer (score 0):

I updated @Blazzze IL's answer to support multiple occurrences of asterisks: For a string, where multiple words should be written in bold each with a star (*) at start and end.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { noop } from 'rxjs';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'boldText'
})
export class BoldTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: string): any {
    const regex = /\*([^,*]+)\*/gmi;
    return this.sanitize(this.replace(value, regex));
  }

  replace(str: string, regex: RegExp) {
    let matched = str.match(regex);
    matched ? matched.forEach((foundString: string) => {
      var newString = foundString.substring(1, foundString.length - 1);
      str = str.replace(foundString, `<b>${newString}</b>`);
    }) : noop;
    return str;
  }

  sanitize(str: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, str);
  }
}
```

HTML: `<p [innerHTML]="text | boldText"></p>`