# How to add CSS styles to a particular interpolation in angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a simple message to be displayed but the content inside {{ selectedName }} alone should be displayed in bold. Is there any way to add this style to this particular interpolation alone ?

```
 `<p class="confirmation-text">{{ confirmationMessage | translate }} "{{ selectedName }}" ? </p>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipe follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241923/4964569

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Sanitizer, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'bold'
    })
    export class BoldPipe implements PipeTransform {

      constructor(
        private sanitizer: Sanitizer
      ) {}

      transform(value: string, regex): any {
        return this.sanitize(this.replace(value, regex));
      }

      replace(str, regex) {
        return str.replace(new RegExp(`(${regex})`, 'gi'), '<b>$1</b>');
      }

      sanitize(str) {
        return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, str);
      }
    }
```

And use as `<p class="confirmation-text">{{ confirmationMessage }} "{{ selectedName | bold }}" ? </p>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="confirmation-text">
    {{ confirmationMessage | translate }} 
    <strong>
       {{ selectedName }} 
    </strong>
</p>
```

this will help you, just upvote :)