# How do we make text bold from .ts file to show in [innterText] html section

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bold, innertext

Just like we use \n instead of 
 to see the line break changes in the interface, how do we bold the specific text? What can be the alternative solution apart from using [innerHTML]?

for example:
**.ts file**

string = `This is a STRING bold testing.\n Thankyou!`; // here I want to word STRING to be bold

**.html file**

```
<h2 [innerText]="string"></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a custom Pipe for making bold for a particular string. Please find the below URL for your reference.

[apply bold text on part of string Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241693/apply-bold-text-on-part-of-string-angular)

Comment: thankyou @frangly but this solution is using [innerHTML], I actually need to show output using [innerText]