# Replace irregular part of strings in Angular

Tags: angular, replace, regexp-replace, angular13

I am looking to replace parts of multiple strings to **bold** text in Angular 13.
I am fetching the text from an external API.

It is the middle part of the string that has to be highlighted. I am mapping the strings to render it on my page. There are 3 in total.

Optimal result:

- Whether it’s **helping doctors detect diseases earlier** or **enabling people to access information** in their own language
- Since then we’ve **continued to make investments in AI** across the board, and Google AI and DeepMind are advancing the state of the art.
- We’ve been working on an **experimental conversational AI service** powered by LaMDa

The words to be bold are in different places in these sentences. Therefore I can not replace specific words.

I have checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241693/apply-bold-text-on-part-of-string-angular) and are planning to use PipeTransform. Would regex be the answer in this case?
Would appreciate help on this.

Comment: You'd be better off using a directive than a pipe. A pipe formats data, and using one to add HTML tags to a string is really not a good idea. Do you know in advance which text will be bold? Are you using some kind of parsing (Markdown for example)?

Comment: Ok! Yes I know in advance what text that should be bold. The grammar will differ between the 10 languages, but for me the most important one now is english. No parsing.

Comment: What directive would be suitable when the words in different sentences are unique?

Comment: You create one. You build a directive which looks for the words and replaces them with HTML elements (`<span>` for example) with your bold text class/style.