# Angular: How do I use dynamic text for data binded input

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I want to dynamically change the styling of select words in a sentence (with a custom pipe) like so:

```
<p>{{ product.sentence | italicArray:product.italicsArray }}</p>
```

This creates:

```
Hi this is a <span><i>test</i></span> sentence
```

How do I enforce the *span* and *italics* tags and not display them as clear text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can loop through the italics array
- then we use regex `new RegExp('\\b' + str + '\\b', 'g')` to get all the whole words with the match string and then wrap it around `<i><i/>`
- We can use `DomSantizer` to sanitize the transformed data.
- Finally since we have HTML in the code now, we need to render it on `innerHTML` which will give us the desired output, but there is a catch, we cannot have angular events/binding since its rendering outside the angular context

[Answer from Blazzze IL helped this answer do Upvote that answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241693/apply-bold-text-on-part-of-string-angular)

Working example below

pipe

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Sanitizer, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'italicArray',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ItalicArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string, strArray = []): any {
    let output: string = value;
    strArray.forEach((str: string) => {
      output = <string>this.sanitize(this.replace(output, str));
    });
    return output;
  }

  replace(value: string, str: string): string {
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + str + '\\b', 'g');
    str = value.replace(regex, `<i>${str}</i>`);
    return str;
  }

  sanitize(str: string) {
    console.log(this.sanitizer);
    return this.sanitizer?.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, str) || '';
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Component, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import 'zone.js';
import { ItalicArrayPipe } from './italic-array.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ItalicArrayPipe],
  template: `
    <p [innerHTML]="product.sentence | italicArray: product.italicsArray"></p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  product: any = {
    sentence:
      'Hi this is a test sentence, which is a working example, and is the final solution',
    italicsArray: ['test', 'is'],
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uwyeqc?file=src%2Fitalic-array.pipe.ts,src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much! I did the pipe already actually haha. But I couldn't get the tags to display. Now i see it requires "sanitising"